# How to post Multiple Json Fields/Objects in Django using JavaScipt

Tags: json, django, serialization

I am Following a Short Tutorial on Django API where I have extended the Model to include a couple more Fields

I can get the Front End working but can not Post data for the new Fields

The Block of Code Below is where I would like to add a few more Fields to Post..., at least that is where I think it should go...??

```
        var title = document.getElementById('title').value
        fetch(url, {
            method:'POST',
            headers:{
                'Content-type':'application/json',
                'X-CSRFToken':csrftoken,
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({'title': title
            })
        }
        ).then(function(response){
            buildList()
            document.getElementById('form').reset()
        })
    })
```

**** Model ****

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=75, blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.FloatField(default='0.00')
    productdesc = models.CharField(db_column='ProductDesc', max_length=75, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    producttype = models.CharField(db_column='ProductType', max_length=75, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    producttypefamily = models.CharField(db_column='ProductTypeFamily', max_length=75, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    numworkstation = models.IntegerField(db_column='Numworkstation', default='0')  # Field name made lowercase.
    numserver = models.IntegerField(db_column='Numserver', default='0')  # Field name made lowercase.
    addlconsole = models.IntegerField(db_column='addlconsole', default='0')  # Field name made lowercase.
    productcomplexitybase = models.FloatField(db_column='ProductComplexityBase', default='550')  # Field name made lowercase.
    productcomplexityfac = models.FloatField(db_column='ProductComplexityFac', default='1.0')  # Field name made lowercase.
    digital = models.BooleanField(default=False,null=True, blank=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
```

```
***** view.py *****

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import JsonResponse

from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .serializers import TaskSerializer

from .models import Task
# Create your views here.

@api_view(['GET'])
def apiOverview(request):
    api_urls = {
        'List':'/task-list/',
        'Detail View':'/task-detail/<str:pk>/',
        'Create':'/task-create/',
        'Update':'/task-update/<str:pk>/',
        'Delete':'/task-delete/<str:pk>/',
        }

    return Response(api_urls)

@api_view(['GET'])
def taskList(request):
    tasks = Task.objects.all().order_by('-id')
    serializer = TaskSerializer(tasks, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

@api_view(['GET'])
def taskDetail(request, pk):
    tasks = Task.objects.get(id=pk)
    serializer = TaskSerializer(tasks, many=False)
    return Response(serializer.data)


@api_view(['POST'])
def taskCreate(request):
    serializer = TaskSerializer(data=request.data)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()

    return Response(serializer.data)

@api_view(['POST'])
def taskUpdate(request, pk):
    task = Task.objects.get(id=pk)
    serializer = TaskSerializer(instance=task, data=request.data)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()

    return Response(serializer.data)


@api_view(['DELETE'])
def taskDelete(request, pk):
    task = Task.objects.get(id=pk)
    task.delete()

    return Response('Item succsesfully delete!')
```

```
***** list.html  ****
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>TO DO</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <style type="text/css">
        body{
          background: rgb(54,217,182);
          background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(54,217,182,1) 0%, rgba(32,152,126,1) 43%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 100%);
        }


        h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, p, span, strike{
          font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;

        }


        #task-container{
          max-width:900px;
          margin:0 auto;
          box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
          background-color: #fff;
          
          margin-top:100px;
          margin-bottom:100px;

          justify-content: space-around;
          align-items: flex-start;

        }

        #form-wrapper{
          position: -webkit-sticky;
          position: sticky;
          top: 0rem;
          border-bottom: 1px solid  #e9e9e9;
          background-color: #fff;
          box-shadow: 0 3px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
          padding:40px;
        }

        #submit{
          background-color: #36d9b6;
          border-radius: 0;
          border:0;
          color: #fff;
        }

        .flex-wrapper{
            display: flex;
        }

        .task-wrapper{
            margin:5px;
            padding: 5px;
            padding:20px;
            cursor: pointer;
            border-bottom: 1px solid  #e9e9e9;
            color: #686868;
            }

    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">

        <div id="task-container">
            <div id="form-wrapper">
                <form id="form">
                    <div class="flex-wrapper">
                        <div style="flex: 6">
                            <input id="title" class="form-control" type="text" name="title" placeholder="Add task">
                        </div>
                        <div style="flex: 5">
                            <input id="numserver" class="form-control" type="text" name="numserver" placeholder="Enter # Svrs">
                        </div>
                        <div style="flex: 5">
                            <input id="numworkstation" class="form-control" type="text" name="numworkstation" placeholder="Enter # Wkstns">
                        </div>
                        <div style="flex: 1">
                            <input id="submit" class="btn" type="submit">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

            <div id="list-wrapper">
            
            </div>  
        </div>

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        /*
            KEY COMPONENTS:
            "activeItem" = null until an edit button is clicked. Will contain object of item we are editing
            "list_snapshot" = Will contain previous state of list. Used for removing extra rows on list update
            
            PROCESS:
            1 - Fetch Data and build rows "buildList()"
            2 - Create Item on form submit
            3 - Edit Item click - Prefill form and change submit URL
            4 - Delete Item - Send item id to delete URL
            5 - Cross out completed task - Event handle updated item

            NOTES:
            -- Add event handlers to "edit", "delete", "title"
            -- Render with strike through items completed
            -- Remove extra data on re-render
            -- CSRF Token
        */

        function getCookie(name) {
            var cookieValue = null;
            if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
                var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
                for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                    var cookie = cookies[i].trim();
                    // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                    if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                        cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return cookieValue;
        }
        var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

        var activeItem = null
        var list_snapshot = []

        buildList()

        function buildList(){
            var wrapper = document.getElementById('list-wrapper')
            //wrapper.innerHTML = ''



            var url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/task-list/'

            fetch(url)
            .then((resp) => resp.json())
            .then(function(data){
                console.log('Data:', data)

                var list = data
                for (var i in list){


                    try{
                        document.getElementById(`data-row-${i}`).remove()
                    }catch(err){

                    }
            


                    var title = `<span class="title">${list[i].title}</span>`
                    var numserver = `<span class="numserver">${list[i].numserver}</span>`
                    var numworkstation = `<span class="numworkstion">${list[i].numworkstation}</span>`

                    if (list[i].completed == true){
                        title = `<strike class="title">${list[i].title}</strike>`
                        numserver = `<strike class="numserver">${list[i].numserver}</strike>`
                        numworkstation = `<strike class="numworkstation">${list[i].numworkstation}</strike>`

                    }

                    var item = `
                        <div id="data-row-${i}" class="task-wrapper flex-wrapper">
                            <div style="flex:6">
                                ${title}
                            </div>
                            <div style="flex:5">
                                ${numserver}
                            </div>
                            <div style="flex:5">
                                ${numworkstation}
                            </div>
                            <div style="flex:1">
                                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-info edit">Edit </button>
                            </div>
                            <div style="flex:1">
                                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-dark delete">-</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    `
                    wrapper.innerHTML += item
    
                }

                if (list_snapshot.length > list.length){
                    for (var i = list.length; i < list_snapshot.length; i++){
                        document.getElementById(`data-row-${i}`).remove()
                    }
                }

                list_snapshot = list


                for (var i in list){
                    var editBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('edit')[i]
                    var deleteBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('delete')[i]
                    var title = document.getElementsByClassName('title')[i]
                    //var numserver = document.getElementsByClassName('numserver')[i]
     //               var numworkstation = document.getElementsByClassName('numworkstation')[i]


                    editBtn.addEventListener('click', (function(item){
                        return function(){
                            editItem(item)
                        }
                    })(list[i]))


                    deleteBtn.addEventListener('click', (function(item){
                        return function(){
                            deleteItem(item)
                        }
                    })(list[i]))



                    
                    title.addEventListener('click', (function(item){
                        return function(){
                            strikeUnstrike(item)
                        }
                    })(list[i]))


                }


            })
        }


        var form = document.getElementById('form-wrapper')
        form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
            e.preventDefault()
            console.log('Form submitted')
            var url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/task-create/'
            if (activeItem != null){
                var url = `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/task-update/${activeItem.id}/`
                activeItem = null
            }



            var title = document.getElementById('title').value
            fetch(url, {
                method:'POST',
                headers:{
                    'Content-type':'application/json',
                    'X-CSRFToken':csrftoken,
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({'title': title
                })
            }
            ).then(function(response){
                buildList()
                document.getElementById('form').reset()
            })
        })




        function editItem(item){
            console.log('Item clicked:', item)
            activeItem = item
            document.getElementById('title').value = activeItem.title
        }


        function deleteItem(item){
            console.log('Delete clicked')
            fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/task-delete/${item.id}/`, {
                method:'DELETE', 
                headers:{
                    'Content-type':'application/json',
                    'X-CSRFToken':csrftoken,
                }
            }).then((response) => {
                buildList()
            })
        }

        function strikeUnstrike(item){
            console.log('Strike clicked')

            item.completed = !item.completed
            fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/task-update/${item.id}/`, {
                method:'POST', 
                headers:{
                    'Content-type':'application/json',
                    'X-CSRFToken':csrftoken,
                },
                body:JSON.stringify({'title':item.title, 'completed':item.completed})
            }).then((response) => {
                buildList()
            })
        }


    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`print(serializers.errors)` if `is_valid()` fails.. and correct the errors...

Comment: when you call `serializer.is_valid()`,  it may return true or false. if true, you can access serializer.validated_data to see the "ready to use data" like form's `cleaned_data`. if it returns false, then you can access serializer.errors to see why it not passed.

Comment: I am trying to add two more fields to the Post , numserver, and numworkstation

`
   var title = document.getElementById('title').value
   fetch(url, {
    method:'POST',
    headers:{
     'Content-type':'application/json',
     'X-CSRFToken':csrftoken,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
     'title': title,
     'numserver': numserver,
                    'numworkstation': numworkstation

    })
   }
   ).then(function(response){
    buildList()
    document.getElementById('form').reset()
   })
  })

`